# Convertir código a java

Tags: java

Tengo que hacer el siguiente programa " Crear un programa en Java que obtenga la solución de un sistema de ecuaciones lineales por medio de la descomposición LU" apoyado de este video https://youtu.be/YjgvZ9XIMZA intente hacer lo mismo pero en java. El problema es que como yo maneje números enteros no salen los valores que deberían salir. Adjunto el código para ver si me pueden ayudar a obtener los valores correctos como en el video. También cambia en que en mi caso yo le pido al usuario los valores de la matriz no se si afecte eso o no tenga nada que ver, si quieren compílenlo y verán que funciona pero los valores los da en cantidades raras y  si meten la matriz del video salen los mismos valores pero como no es double cambia y se ve mal. Por favor ayúdenme.

```
//Ecuaciones lineales

import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ecuaciones {

public static void mostrar(int[][] m, int ecu) {
    for (int e = 0; e < ecu; e++) {
        for (int r = 0; r < ecu; r++) {
            System.out.println("{0}" + m[e][r]);

        }
        System.out.println();
    }
    System.out.println("-------------");
}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int filas = 3, columnas = 4;
    int ecu = 3;
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[][] A = new int[filas][columnas]; // Se crea una matriz de 5 filas y 4 columnas

    // Se introducen por teclado los valores de la matriz
    System.out.println("Lectura de elementos de la matriz: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < filas; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < columnas; j++) {
            System.out.print("A[" + i + "]" + "[" + j + "]= ");
            A[i][j] = sc.nextInt();
        }

    }

    // Mostrar por pantalla los valores que contiene la matriz

    System.out.println("valores introducidos:");
    for (int a = 0; a < A.length; a++) {

        for (int b = 0; b < A[a].length; b++) {
            System.out.print(A[a][b] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    // reduccion hacia adelante

    for (int t = 0; t < ecu + 1; t++) {
        A[0][t] = A[0][t] / A[0][0];
        for (int k = 1; k < ecu; k++) {
            for (int x = k; x < ecu; x++) {
                for (int l = 0; l < k; l++) {
                    A[x][k] = A[x][k] - A[x][l] * A[l][k];

                    for (int y = k + 1; y < ecu + 1; y++) {
                        for (int w = 0; w < k; w++) {
                            A[k][t] = A[k][ecu] - A[k][l] * A[l][t];
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }

    // sustitucion por atras

    for (int u = ecu - 1; u >= 0; u--) {
        for (int v = u + 1; v < ecu; v++) {
            A[u][ecu] = A[u][ecu] - A[u][v] * A[v][ecu];

        }

    }
    mostrar(A, ecu);

    // resultados
    for (int f = 0; f < ecu; f++) {
        System.out.println("{0}={1}" + f + A[f][ecu]);
    }

}
}
```

Comment: Si el problema es que manejas enteros, basta con cambiar el tipo de dato a float o a double

Answer (score 0):

hay que ver donde colocar las llaves exactamente,y es necesario que la matriz sea de tipo double para obtener la respuesta que necesitas ,como método final tendrías los siguiente, como prueba puedes ingrese los datos de tu ejemplo {2,-1,1,2},{-1,3,3,3},{2,1,4,1}

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program{

public static void main(String[] args) {

Scanner dc=new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("ESTA ES UNA MATRIZ DE 3 x 4");
System.out.println("Ingrese valores para la matriz");
//{2,-1,1,2},{-1,3,3,3},{2,1,4,1}
double [][]matriz=new double [3][4];

for (int x=0;x<3;x++ ) {
    for (int y=0;y<4;y++ ) {
        matriz[x][y]=dc.nextDouble();
    }
}
    int n=3;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int l=0;

// ADELANTE

    for (j=1;j<n+1;j++) 
        matriz[0][j]=matriz[0][j]/matriz[0][0];

     for (k=1;k<n;k++ ) 
        {
         for (i=k;i<n;i++ ) 
            for (l=0;l<k;l++ ) 
                matriz[i][k]=matriz[i][k]-matriz[i][l]*matriz[l][k];
                    
                 for (j=k+1;j<n+1;j++ ) 
                    {
                      for (l=0;l<k;l++ )
                        matriz[k][j]=matriz[k][n]-matriz[k][l]*matriz[l][j];            

                           matriz[k][j]=matriz[k][j]/matriz[k][k];

            }
         }
        
  
        //sustitucion para atras
        for (k=n-1;k>=0;--k) 
        {
          for (l=k+1;l<n;l++ )
            {
              matriz[k][n]=matriz[k][n]-matriz[k][l]*matriz[l][n];  
             }   
        }
       System.out.println("\n");
       System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(matriz)+"\n");


       //imprime resultados
       
     for (i=0;i<n;i++ ) {
        System.out.println("x["+i+"]= "+matriz[i][n]);
      } 


  }
 }
```